# Artifacts When Plotting Results of Numerical Integration

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to reproduce the following graph of phase shifts as function of frequency.
[image]
Please see my code bellow. I used Mathematica to solve for `t1` and `t2` analytically so that is how I got `t1` and `t2`. The plot I get seems to have some weird artifacts like gaps, discontinuities and dark patches. I don't understand why these artifacts are there, any help is appreciated. I am using Mathematica 12.0 Student Edition if that helps.

My code:

```
Q[r_, l_, w_] := 
  Sqrt[(-l(1+l)(-(2/r^3)+1/r^2)+1/r^4+w^2)/(1-2/r)^2-1/(4(-2+r)^2)];

t1[l_, w_] := (1/2)*Sqrt[-((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)/(6*w^2)) + ((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)/(6*2^(2/3)*w^2*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 +Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)) +(1/(12*2^(1/3)*w^2))*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)] + (1/2)*Sqrt[-((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)/(3*w^2)) - ((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)/(6*2^(2/3)*w^2*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)) - (1/(12*2^(1/3)*w^2))*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3) - (4*(l + l^2))/(w^2*Sqrt[-((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)/(6*w^2)) + ((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)/(6*2^(2/3)*w^2*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)) + (1/(12*2^(1/3)*w^2))*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)])];

t2[l_, w_] := (1/2)*Sqrt[-((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)/(6*w^2)) + ((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)/(6*2^(2/3)*w^2*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)) + (1/(12*2^(1/3)*w^2))*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)] - (1/2)*Sqrt[-((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)/(3*w^2)) - ((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)/(6*2^(2/3)*w^2*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)) - (1/(12*2^(1/3)*w^2))*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3) - (4*(l + l^2))/(w^2*Sqrt[-((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)/(6*w^2)) + ((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)/(6*2^(2/3)*w^2*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)) + (1/(12*2^(1/3)*w^2))*(2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2 + Sqrt[-4*((-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^2 + 192*w^2)^3 + (2*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)^3 - 1152*(-1 - 4*l - 4*l^2)*w^2 + 6912*(l + l^2)^2*w^2)^2])^(1/3)])];

\[Gamma][l_, w_] := NIntegrate[Q[r, l, w], {r, t2[l, w], t1[l, w]}];
\[Eta][l_, w_] := NIntegrate[Q[r, l, w] - w*(r/(r - 2)), {r, t2[l, w], Infinity}] - w*(t2[l, w] + 2*Log[(t2[l, w]/2) - 1]);
\[Sigma][l_, w_] := (-1/(4*I))*Log[Gamma[(1/2) - (\[Gamma][l, w]/Pi)]/Gamma[(1/2) + (\[Gamma][l, w]/Pi)]] + ((I*\[Gamma][l, w])/(2*Pi))*Log[I*\[Gamma][l, w]/Pi] - (I*\[Gamma][l, w])/(2*Pi);
b0[l_, w_] := I*Exp[2 I*\[Sigma][l, w]]*Exp[I*\[Gamma][l, w]]*((1 + Exp[2 I*\[Gamma][l, w]])^(1/2)); 
\[Delta][l_, w_] := \[Eta][l, w] - (1/(2*I)) Log[b0[l, w]] + (l + 1) (Pi/2);

Plot[{l = 0; Re[\[Delta][l, w]], 
      l = 1; Re[\[Delta][l, w]], 
      l = 2; Re[\[Delta][l, w]], 
      l = 3; Re[\[Delta][l, w]]}, {w, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> "Re[\[Delta]] vs w"]

Plot[{l = 0; Im[\[Delta][l, w]],
      l = 1; Im[\[Delta][l, w]],
      l = 2; Im[\[Delta][l, w]],
      l = 3; Im[\[Delta][l, w]]}, {w, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> "Im[\[Delta]] vs w"]
```

When I run my code I also get these kinds of errors:

```
NIntegrate: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the \following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly \oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
NIntegrate: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 \recursive bisections in r near {r} = {6.3887*10^56+0.\ I}. NIntegrate \obtained 9.92960347731536*10^6986+5.27362\ I and \ 9.92960347731536`15.954589770191005*^6986 for the integral and error \estimates.
```

and the plots I get are:

[image]

[image]

I also tried to use different settings of  `MaxRecursion` and `PrecisionGoal` in NIntegrate but that didn't seem to work. Another thing is that when t1 and t2 are being evaluated there are small rounding errors and I tried to use `Chop@t1[l,w]` and `Chop@t2[l,w]` for the limits of integration instead but that did not give me the correct plots either. I am not sure if this is a matter of learning how to use mathematica better or if I should use another tool instead, please advise. Thank you.

Edit: To clarify, Mathematica yields 4 roots for Q(r)=0 so how did I determine which ones are t1 and t2? I know the nature of the roots I'm looking for a priori. For a fixed l, the roots I'm looking for are real bellow a cut off value of w, above this value of w the roots are complex conjugates of each other (t1 in the upper half of the complex plane and t2 in the lower). When I tested (by plotting the real parts and imaginary parts of the roots (for a fixed l) as functions of w) it was clear that only those two particular ones fit this criteria. In addition when using any of the other two roots (i.e the invalid ones) the resulting plot for the phase shift does not resemble the one I'm trying to reproduce at all. This is how I determined which of the 4 roots correspond to t1 and t2.

Comment: There are 4 roots, how do you choose t1 and t2?

Comment: Hi @OkkesDulgerci apologies for the very late response. I needed to take time off from working on this for personal reasons. If you are still willing to assist here is the answer to your question: I know the nature of the roots I'm looking for a priori. For a fixed l, the roots I'm looking for are real bellow a cut off value of w, above this value of w the roots are complex conjugates of each other. When I tested (by plotting the real parts and imaginary parts of the roots (for a fixed l) as functions of w) it was clear that only those two particular ones fit this criteria.